# Applescript list of loved albums

Tags: applescript, itunes

How can i, as the title indicates, get a list of all loved albums from iTunes in applescript.

I have a code that works for playlist but it is not as simple as changing the word `playlist` to `album` because the album name(as well as its loved status) is stored as part of the song, where as a playlist is a list of songs.

Currently i have:

```
    tell application "iTunes" to set PLs to the name of every playlist whose
        loved is true as text
    set PL to (choose from list PLs with title "Playlist") as text
```

Also a list of all followed artists would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this only with a repeat loop by getting all loved tracks and create two lists for albums and artists

```
set lovedAlbums to {}
set lovedArtists to {}
tell application "iTunes"
    set lovedTracks to every track whose loved is true
    repeat with aTrack in lovedTracks
        tell album of aTrack to if lovedAlbums does not contain it then set end of lovedAlbums to it
        tell artist of aTrack to if lovedArtists does not contain it then set end of lovedArtists to it
    end repeat
end tell
set TID to text item delimiters
set text item delimiters to return
set lovedAlbumText to lovedAlbums as text
set lovedArtistsText to lovedArtists as text
set text item delimiters to TID
display dialog lovedAlbumText & return & return & lovedArtistsText buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK"
```

Comment: Thanks, only needed the first 9 lines though, works perfectly